# Best way to translate 见闻 in a sentence

Tags: translation, usage

In the song 记得忘记 (jìde wàngjì, memories and forgetfulness / remembering and forgetting), there is the following sentence:

> 你赠我太多见闻    拿不走的热吻 | Nǐ zèng wǒ tài duō jiànwén    ná bù zǒu de rèwěn

I would instinctively interpret 见闻 (jiànwén) as an adjective going with 拿不走 (ná bù zǒu) to refer to 热吻 (rèwěn). However, I cannot find any adjective sense of 见闻 (jiànwén) on the Wiktionary nor on Google, and since the lyrics are usually given with a linebreak after 见闻 (jiànwén), it might be that 见闻 (jiànwén) is actually another noun going with 热吻 (rèwěn) to be the object of 赠 (zèng). So:

- Translation 1: "You gave me too many  warm kisses I couldn't take away;
- Translation 2: "You gave me too many experiences [and] warm kisses I couldn't take away.

Which one is the best (or possibly the only correct one)? And if the best is option 1, what  should I use?

Comment: I think the translation 2 is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

见闻 is a noun word in the context, meaning "what one sees and hears; knowledge and information". Interpreting as "experiences" in this context is ok I think.

Your statement is correct:

> "since the lyrics are usually given with a linebreak after 见闻
>   (jiànwén), it might be that 见闻 (jiànwén) is actually another noun
>   going with 热吻 (rèwěn) to be the object of 赠 (zèng). "

Small tweaks on your translation 2: "You gave me too many experiences [and] warm kisses **that couldn't be taken away**."

Comment: I guess that tweak doesn't change the meaning that much. To me, it only prevents the nitpick that the singer couldn't take away the kisses but perhaps someone else could, which sounds like pure, err, tauricopria to me. Is there anything more to it in your view?

Comment: The logic is 你赠我 见闻 和 热吻. It means those kisses have already given to you, why do you need to take them away from yourself? It doesn't make sense you take them away. My take to this is that the singer conveys that he wouldn't forget those kisses, because no one could literally take those kisses away. It's just an expression.

Comment: So "that noone can take away [from me]". Now I see it.

Comment: By the way, what does it mean by "like pure, err, tauricopria "? I don't quite get it.

Comment: "Tauricopria" is a euphemism I made up myself. "Taurus" means "bull" in Greek and Latin, and the -copria part comes from "kopros", Greek for "feces". So "bull-feces". Get it now :)?

Comment: oh, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a soul song, right? Soul songs need lots of 'oh baby'.

你赠我太多见闻
You gave me so much (we should put an 'oh baby' here)
拿不走的热吻
your warm kisses linger in my mind (oh baby)
我们为什么分手
why did we break up? （oh baby)
记得呢你有口臭
oh I remember, you have bad breath (oh baby)

Comment: That is not the song I found on Youtube. Also, this does not directly address the question, so it is borderline NAA. My song continues with «多努力放低   偏不会忘记   苦恋纪念品».

Comment: sense of humour??

Answer (score 0):

见闻,i  would like to separate it into 2 word "见"and"闻"
见，in chinese,it usually means looks or read,experience.
闻，simply is hear.we all know that when we learn something,we should see and hear .so ""见闻 can easily explain as 看到的事和听到的事，more is means "knowledge""or experience